# How to make matched text bold with jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am wondering how to make the matched part of the autocomplete suggestions bold when using jquery ui autocomplete?

So for example if you type in "ja" and the suggestions are javascript and java (like in the example on the jquery ui demo page) then I would like to make "ja" bold in both suggestions.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Thanks a lot for the help...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I'm not sure why the autocomplete is so bare-bone compared to the other functionalities it contains (e.g. droppable, sortable, draggable etc.).

It should really offer you with a stylable option, e.g. wrapping it with `<span class="ui-autocomplete-term">term</span>` or something similar.

You could do it like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wyVJW/894/)

It should be pretty self-explanatory; if not, gimme a shout.

Comment: Yes, the example is almost perfect, but it messes up the styling... If I replace find('li') with find('a') it is all good. Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: ignore-case version http://jsfiddle.net/fozylet/kTAMm/  Got the idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957207/highlight-multiple-keywords-for-jquery-autocomplete)

Comment: in IE9, error: "Unable to get value of the property 'menu': object is null or undefined"

Comment: Yep, Imo it should be case insensitive.

Comment: I'd probably recommend doing a `trim()` at the end of the `join('|')` statement in that ignore-case jsfiddle, that way matches like "person ", where they type the initial space ready for next word would also match.

Answer (score 40):

In jQuery UI 1.11.1, here is the code I used to make it work (case insensitive):

```
open: function (e, ui) {
    var acData = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
    acData
    .menu
    .element
    .find('li')
    .each(function () {
        var me = $(this);
        var keywords = acData.term.split(' ').join('|');
        me.text(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), '<b>$1</b>'));
     });
 }
```

Comment: In 2015, this is the answer :)

Comment: Best answer. Simple solution.

Comment: Simple and best solution.

Comment: me.text(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), '<b>$1</b>'));

replace text with html after me.text

Comment: `me.html(me.text...` in the last line to avoid printing tags as entities such as `<b>sea</b>`

Comment: replace `me.text(...` part with this: `let textWrapper = me.find('.ui-menu-item-wrapper'); let text = textWrapper.text(); let newTextHtml = text.replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), '<b>$1</b>'); textWrapper.html(newTextHtml);` to keep the highlight color.

Comment: Thank You @SaidbakR to save my a lot of time.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using [`jquery-ui.js`](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js):

```
acData = $(this).data('autocomplete');// will not work 
//instead use 
acData = $(this).data('uiAutocomplete');
```

Answer (score 20):

Here's a solution for those who want to search case insensitive (only the open function is diffirent):

```
        open: function(e,ui) {
            var
            acData = $(this).data('autocomplete');

            acData
            .menu
            .element
            .find('a')
            .each(function() {
                var me = $(this);
                var regex = new RegExp(acData.term, "gi");
                me.html( me.text().replace(regex, function (matched) {
                    return termTemplate.replace('%s', matched);
                }) );
            });
        }
```

Comment: -@brechtvhb Is this your answer or @fozylet's? If @fozylet's can you give them credit?

Comment: How could I have based my answer (apr 23 2011) on fozylet's answer (jan 18 2012)?

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery UI 1.9.x this solution did not work for me because acData was undefined - the data reference timing was wrong because I init my PluginHelper before the document ready.

I came up to mod the _renderItem using jQuery UIs widget factory:

```
$.widget("custom.autocompleteHighlight", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
        var regexp = new RegExp('(' + this.term + ')', 'gi'),
            classString = this.options.HighlightClass ?  ' class="' + this.options.highlightClass + '"' : '',
            label = item.label.replace(regexp, '<span' + classString + '>$1</span>');

        return $('<li><a href="#">' + label + '</a></li>').appendTo(ul);
    }
});
```

You now can use it with:

```
$('input.jsAutocompleteHighlight').autocompleteHighlight({
        highlightClass: 'ui-autocomplete-highlight'
});
```

CSS styling:

```
.ui-autocomplete-highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. B.t.w. there's a typo in your class name: 'ui-autocomplete-hightlight' instead of 'ui-autocomplete-highlight'