# Make li item bold

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using Jquery autocomplete for Google suggestions. I would like to make the li items in the autocomplete suggestions **bold** if they match the value of input. I first tried to do this with an event but I realized that the event would be triggered after the request so that wouldn't work. So now I'm trying to make font bold right in the autocomplete with:

```
var val = $('#searchbox').val();

    if (val == $(item.suggestion.data).html()) {
      $(item.suggestion.data).css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
```

This doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why. Here is an example of the autocomplete: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpKj6/4/)

Comment: You can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344804/how-to-make-matched-text-bold-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the autocomplete's open event to match the input text against the values returned in the autocomplete's drop down list.

```
open: function(event, ui) {
    $('.ui-menu li a').each(function(){
    if($(this).text()==$('#searchbox').val()) $(this).wrap('<strong>');
    });
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QpKj6/24/)**.

Comment: Hi, I wrapped it in .div with font-size 12px, please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/QpKj6/25/ but it doesn't work..(Your link also doesn't work)

Comment: I have noticed they are bold now but in my example they are not.??? Where is this coming from??

Comment: @Youss - What do you mean my link doesn't work? When you type something in the input field and it matches one of the autocomplete results, that result gets bolded. Try entering "aldi".

Comment: @Youss - That's because you can't use wrap with a class. Wrap is for wrapping elements around something else. Try addClass instead. Ex: `        if($(this).text()==$('#searchbox').val()) $(this).addClass("div");` and http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QpKj6/26/

Comment: Sorry..you are right, it does work. I was a bit confused becouse its not the effect I was looking for. Its not 'exactly' the value that needs to match but the 'words' themselves..So typing 'aldi' ...:) would bold every 'aldi' in the list, not just the first one. But I realize I should have rephrased my question...

Comment: @Youss - Were you looking to bold the first matching characters of each item in the autocomplete list like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QpKj6/28/?

Comment: Yep that's what I was looking for. Thanks for coming back:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Make modifications to the various list items in the handler.

Comment: @Youss Good luck, let me know if you have more questions, although I don't know JQuery syntax myself to be honest. But I can explain what you need to do in logical terms.