# I want to highlight words i enter in autocomplete search bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

[I want to achieve this in below mention code need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol5D4.png) 
i want to highlight text in auto complete same like pic i added above

```
<?php 
$query = isset($_GET['query']) ? $_GET['query'] : FALSE;
global $wpdb;
    // escape values passed to db to avoid sql-injection
$depts = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_paklog_service WHERE service_name LIKE '".$query."%'" );
$suggestions = array();
$data = array();
foreach($depts as $row) {
        $suggestions[] = $row->service_name;
        $data[] = $row->id;
}
json_encode ($suggestions);
?>
//this is js code 
var obj = <?php echo json_encode($suggestions); ?>;
jQuery(".search-services").autocomplete({
      source: function( request, response ) {
      var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + jQuery.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
      response( jQuery.grep( obj, function( item ){
          return matcher.test( item );

      }) );
  }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344804/how-to-make-matched-text-bold-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: but this shows all results e.g f refine, fire i wan t this with auto complete which matches starting words e.g f fire, fine

Comment: Could you please remove the PHP part and show us your exact JS code (replace the PHP code with the actual JSON object)?

Comment: My json obj shows data of whole column from db all values are var char formate